# Is it better to post json data or just key-value pairs in Laravel Apis?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

i have developed the Api in Laravel now one of my team member saying that i will post the data in Json format during api call. now what should i do?

is it better to post data in Json format or just use key-value pairs?
please help

Comment: json is the answer. Json van be used in other languages and apps without problem

Comment: please let me know how can i change the code so that it will accept json post because i have already finished the api work. ? please help?

Comment: its interesting how u developed that api in laravel wich by default uses json responses and u dont know what kind of format. Sounds like u dont know what u are even doing.

Comment: @LeoinstanceofKelmendi Ninja'd me! I don't even know if it's possible to send php style key-value pairs in a http message.

Comment: from client side you only can send json format data. So without any question json is best

Comment: @Loek I think he may be referring to POST key/value pairs.

Comment: If you want to know how to convert your responses (without reading the docs? Shame.....) you should post a different question. The current question is sure to be closed by the moderators anyway. It is purely a request for opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Better" is very subjective. Nothing fits EVERY use case (especially if dealing with legacy code), but generally data in an API is transferred using either JSON (in most REST API's) or XML (used in SOAP). Here are some things to consider though:
1) REST is agnostic in that it cares none about what format you use for your data, so there are apps that transmit data as csv, JSON, XML, or anything else you can imagine.

2) I believe the most common thing to see from a true headless API is JSON.

3) As someone mentioned before, JSON plays well with other languages that are often used to consume API's. Most of the time if I am consuming an API it is in Javascript, Java, or Python and all three are very "JSON friendly". This would be my preferred format for this reason.

4) Consider what will be consuming your API now, and in the future and build it to work best and "future proof" as much as possible.

5) Someone else will have to read your code later. Using a well defined, well documented format will be a lot easier than deciphering some method you have to parse data from strings or deal with arrays in some custom manner.Sticking with things like JSON that have become somewhat of a standard for REST will help with that.

6) Laravel response()->json() is available from your controller already. That plus JS's native JSON methods just seem like they were meant to go together.

That is just my view though.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using laravel resources

From docs:

```
    class User extends JsonResource
    {
        /**
        * Transform the resource into an array.
        *
        * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
        * @return array
        */
        public function toArray($request)
        {
            return [
               'id' => $this->id,
               'name' => $this->name,
               'email' => $this->email,
               'created_at' => $this->created_at,
               'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
           ];
        }
    }
```

If you want to return one object

```
Route::get('/user', function () {
    return new UserResource(User::find(1));
});
```

If you want to return a collection

```
Route::get('/user', function () {
    return UserResource::collection(User::all());
});
```

This way you can control what is being returned by the route and it will default to json

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources

Answer (score 0):

Json is very easy to manipulate and is both accessible to php and JavaScript. Parsing your site's data to json opens a wide door of possibilities that will be otherwise dificult. if you are using laravel, you can use the json_encode and json_decode() functions to parse data to and fro or the JSON helper class